# Regex Java. Неправильное выражения

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

В чем ошибка этого регулярного выражения? 
Хочу написать regex, который может включать в себя варианты `dkhodan@gmail.com` или `d.khodan@gmail.com.` или `d-khodan@gmail.com`.
Если убрать `.`, которая обозначает любой знак, тогда все работает. Но с точкой почему-то нет.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("(([a-z]).([a-z])){1,20}[\\@]([a-z]){2,5}[\\.]([a-z]){2,4}");
    Matcher matcher = pt.matcher("d.khodan@gmail.com");
    boolean ft = matcher.matches();

    System.out.println("ft = "+ft);
}
```

Comment: Возможно, должно быть `([a-z]).([a-z]){1,20}`, а не `(([a-z]).([a-z])){1,20}`.

Comment: пробовал так тоже. не работает

Comment: А почему тогда в консоли выводится `ft = true`? [Пример](http://goo.gl/qkiIfy).

Comment: Читайте книжки и изучайте регулярные выражения. Длина вашего регулярного выражения, говорит о том, что вы не знаете не умеете их сокращать и писать правильно. Начните с того, какие символы надо экранировать, а какие нет. Например зачем вы экранируете собаку? вот серия видео, начинайте с самого начала. Там как раз есть про экранирование.
[Регулярные выражения-самое начало](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6UCQNnxBEWY&t "Регулярные экранирование символов")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если прямо отвечать на ваш вопрос, то ошибка в том, что выражение до собаки `(([a-z]).([a-z])){1,20}` ищет только строки, состоящие из групп по три символа (первый символ - любая буква, второй символ - любой символ, третий символ - любая буква). Под это условие подходит только первый адрес. Второй и третий адреса в части до собаки содержат по восемь символов, поэтому заведомо не подойдут под вашу регулярку (количество символов до собаки должно быть кратно трём).

Если убрать точку, то второй и третий адреса подходить под регулярку всё-равно не будут, т. к. в части до собаки содержат не буквенные символы (точка и дефис). Первый адрес подходить будет, т. к. в части до собаки содержится чётное число символов и все символы буквенные.

Вообще, не понятно, какую регулярку вы хотите получить. Все три адреса подходят, например, под такую регулярку `(([a-z]).?([a-z])){1,20}[\\@]([a-z]){2,5}[\\.]([a-z]){2,4}`, а ещё под такую `([a-z.-]){1,20}[\\@]([a-z]){2,5}[\\.]([a-z]){2,4}`, ну и под такую тоже подходят `.*`.

Если вы просто хотите проверить адрес на валидность, то используется гораздо более сложное выражение http://emailregex.com/. Но есть мнение, что делать этого в принципе не нужно https://habrahabr.ru/post/175375/.

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример рабочей регулярки подходящей для ваших требований:

```
([a-z]([\.-][a-z])?){1,20}@[a-z]{2,5}\.[a-z]{2,4}
```